# Android - ActionbarSherlock crashes with exception

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-actionbar

I am getting this exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ShareActionProvider cannot be cast to com.actionbarsherlock.view.ActionProvider
        at com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuInflater$MenuState.readItem(MenuInflater.java:389)
        at com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuInflater.parseMenu(MenuInflater.java:162)
        at com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuInflater.inflate(MenuInflater.java:112)
        at com.marketing.MainActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(MainActivity.java:880)
        at com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(SherlockActivity.java:184)
        at com.actionbarsherlock.ActionBarSherlock.callbackCreateOptionsMenu(ActionBarSherlock.java:559)
        at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockNative.dispatchCreateOptionsMenu(ActionBarSherlockNative.java:65)
        at com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(SherlockActivity.java:149)
        at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:2444)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.preparePanel(PhoneWindow.java:388)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.invalidatePanelMenu(PhoneWindow.java:739)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$1.run(PhoneWindow.java:2833)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

on this method:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    MenuInflater inflater = getSupportMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
    return true;
}
```

on this line:

```
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
```

and here is my main_menu.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">  

<item android:id="@+id/menu_item_share"         
android:showAsAction="ifRoom"         
android:title="Share"         
android:actionProviderClass="android.widget.ShareActionProvider" />  

</menu>
```

What I am trying to do is have the ListNavigation and the ActionbarShare both appear on the navigation bar.  Would anyone know how to fix this crash?

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ActionBarSherlock's MenuInflater expects a `com.actionbarsherlock.view.ActionProvider.`

Your actionProviderClass is an `android.widget.ShareActionProvider` which obviously doesn't extend ActionBarSherlock's ActionProvider. Therefore the ClassCastException.

There are samples included with ActionBarSherlock including some that show the use of ActionProviders. Check out the folder

`ActionBarSherlock\actionbarsherlock-samples\demos\res\menu`

to get two examples of menu xml files and

`ActionBarSherlock\actionbarsherlock-samples\demos\src\com\actionbarsherlock\sample\demos`
 for the according sources

`(ShareActionProviders.java and ActionProviders.java)`

Comment: thank you. I did use the samples and I got it to work with just the ListNavigation. But I am having major difficulties putting 2 elements on the menu: the sharing widget and the ListNavigation

Comment: I just got rid the import of ShareActionProvider but the weird thing is that it compiled. I was expecting it to give a syntax error.

Comment: Well if you describe the nature of the "major difficulties" you encounter I might be able to help. I'm working with ActionBarSherlock and use almost all features including custom list navigation, action providers and more.